# Comparing iterators in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

This

```
from __future__ import print_function

from functools import partial
from itertools import imap, product

identity = lambda x: x
identity.__repr__ = 'id'

map_identity = partial(map, identity)
map_identity.__repr__ = 'map'

imap_identity = partial(imap, identity)
imap_identity.__repr__ = 'imap'

prod_map = partial(product, repeat=1)
prod_map.__repr__ = 'prod'



list(map(
    lambda (f, g):
        print(
            "{f_repr:4}(range(10)) compare {g_repr:4}(range(10)):  "\
            "{{ less: {less:1}, equal: {equal:1}}}".format(
                f_repr=f.__repr__,
                g_repr=g.__repr__,
                less=f(range(16))<g(range(16)),
                equal=f(range(16))==g(range(16)),
            )
        ),
    product([identity, map_identity, imap_identity, prod_map], repeat=2)
))
```

returns

```
id  (range(10)) compare id  (range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 1}
id  (range(10)) compare map (range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 1}
id  (range(10)) compare imap(range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 0}
id  (range(10)) compare prod(range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 0}
map (range(10)) compare id  (range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 1}
map (range(10)) compare map (range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 1}
map (range(10)) compare imap(range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 0}
map (range(10)) compare prod(range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 0}
imap(range(10)) compare id  (range(10)):  { less: 1, equal: 0}
imap(range(10)) compare map (range(10)):  { less: 1, equal: 0}
imap(range(10)) compare imap(range(10)):  { less: 1, equal: 0}
imap(range(10)) compare prod(range(10)):  { less: 1, equal: 0}
prod(range(10)) compare id  (range(10)):  { less: 1, equal: 0}
prod(range(10)) compare map (range(10)):  { less: 1, equal: 0}
prod(range(10)) compare imap(range(10)):  { less: 0, equal: 0}
prod(range(10)) compare prod(range(10)):  { less: 1, equal: 0}
```

what is the reason for the iterators`imap` and `prod_map` to behave differently from the lists `id`/`map` when comparing?

Comment: Interesting. I am more interested in your motivation of doing this

Comment: I think you might not know how `__repr__` is supposed to work. It's supposed to be a method that returns the a string representation of an object, and it has to be set on the object's class, not the instance.

Comment: @user2357112: While it is certainly _misleading_ to reuse the name `__repr__` for an arbitrary string that he wants to access later, there's nothing illegal or broken about it (as evidenced by the fact that his code works). Also, you wouldn't exactly want to set the `__repr__` on the class `types.FunctionType`, would you? (And, if you did, you'd have to explicitly build a descriptor or an unbound method out of it, in Python 2.x, not just set it.)

Comment: Haha, I knew that people would comment on the usage of __repr__, as my defence it was late at night :P

Comment: @sza, I used it for a sanity check that some algorithms performed better than pure chance on a list of scores.
``assert(all(map(gt, *results)))``. But after a while we wanted to use imap instead of map and weird things started to happen..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of separate issues here.

---

First, the result of `map` in 2.x is not an iterator but a list. Two lists are compared by lexicographically comparing their elements.

The same is not true for iterators, and many other iterables (because doing so would consume the iterators, making them useless). So, like most types in Python that don't have any other obvious way to compare them for equality, most iterator types (including generators, and the special C-implemented iterators from `itertools`) compare by `id`. Two different iterators that happen to iterate the same sequence are, in general, not going to be equal.

Of course the result of `identity` is also a list if you pass it a list. And `range(16)` is a list. So, in the cases where both functions are in `(id, map)`, the result will be equal; in cases where either function is in `(imap, prod)`, the result will *not* be equal.

---

Second, using `<` (or other ordering comparisons) on values of two unrelated types gives you a consistent-within-any-run but arbitrary order. Asking why one is less than another is pointless. It has to be one or the other; it doesn't matter which it is. (If you really want to know the details, you can read the source code for your chosen interpreter. CPython's implementation is as simple, and as silly, as you can imagine: values of unrelated types are effectively ordered by their types' canonical names.)

---

So, what if you *want* to know whether two iterators iterate the same sequence?

In general, you can't. For example `chain(0, count(1))` and `count(0)` clearly iterate the same sequence… but it will take you an infinite amount of time to figure that out. (Of course in this case, with enough information about how `chain` and `count` work and access to their internals, you can do it in finite time—at least I hope so, or you're still verifying the "clearly" bit earlier in the paragraph. But you can't do it in general, without solving the halting problem.)

In simple cases, you can just call `list` on each, compare the two lists (and then subsequently use the lists instead of the original, now-empty iterators). In some cases (e.g., you can rely on them to be either different-pretty-early or equal-but-small, but you can't rely on them to be small if different), you can use `tee` and only iterate up to the first difference (and then use the `tee`d copies instead of the original iterators), but this is basically the same idea.

But really, what you probably want is just this:

```
equal_values = (x1 == x2 for x1, x2 in izip(i1, i2))
```

Then you have exactly the same issues as with any other iterator, which you already know how to deal with, right? For example, if you're sure they're not infinite, and you're willing to consume the iterators just to find out if they're equal:

```
equal_sequences = all(equal_values)
```

---

Python 3.x nearly eliminates the first problem by discouraging you from building up lots of intermediate lists for no good reason, and instead encouraging you to keep things in an iterator until you need to iterate them (usually once, at the very end). In particular, `range` doesn't return a `list`—although it does return something that compares equal to itself—and `map` returns an iterator. So, only when both functions are `id` will you get equality.

Python 3.x completely eliminates the second problem by just not letting you compare values of unrelated types. You'll get a `TypeError` if you try. So, you can't be mislead into searching for the non-existent reason why one value is less than the other.

Comment: I would have loved to use python3 for the lazyness but some of the libraries I'm using doesn't support it fully yet :(
Of course, always forgetting that iterators get consumed, then it makes perfect sense, thanks alot man :)

Comment: @SlimJim: What libraries? I ask because more than half the time (and the percentage grows month by month, of course), it turns out that when people say this, they're wrong, and they're just going by some out-of-date blog post that says "You can't use XXX with Python 3" because it was true when the post was written 3 years ago (or because the blogger himself is using 3-year-old knowledge). There certainly are still libraries that aren't 3.x-compatible, but not nearly as many as many people seem to think.

Comment: @SlimJim: Anyway, if you like Python 3, but you're forced to use Python 2, you can get most of the same laziness benefits. The only real difference is that 3.x _encourages_ you to do things lazily, instead of just _allowing_ it. You can always use `imap`, `izip`, `xrange`, etc. instead of `map`, `zip`, `range`, etc. (Or, if you want to write code that acts 3.x-ish under both 2.x and 3.x, take a look at the `six` library.)

Comment: scikit-learn and they are (should) get python3 support on 0.14 but it's not really out yet. (A few other libraries as well but I think they already have support) Yeah the six library looks nice, haven't used it. Perhaps later on we start using python3, but it's not really a priority right now :) Thanks alot for the extensive answer :D

Comment: @SlimJim: If you're going to be working with Python 2.x and 3.x at the same time (which it sounds like you might be in the future), `six` really is worth learning. But porting all of your code to 3.x-ish 2.x code using `six` today probably isn't worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that you weren't comparing the same things to each other, so I decided to walk through it manually. Here's what happened...

```
>>> import functools
>>> from itertools import imap, product
>>> identity = lambda x: x
>>> map_identity = functools.partial(map, identity)
>>> map_identity(range(16))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> map_identity(range(16)) == [x for x in range(16)]
True
```

Of course, that makes sense.

```
>>> imap_identity = functools.partial(imap, identity)
>>> imap_identity(range(16))
<itertools.imap object at 0x10aeb6f50>
```

*Uh oh*.

```
>>> imap_identity(range(16)) < identity
False
>>> imap_identity(range(16)) > identity
True
```

Yep, that'd do it. This actually tripped me up a day or two ago. I thought I was working with a function, but I was working with a generator. You could of course do something like this:

```
>>> im = imap_identity(range(16))
>>> [x for x in im]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

`imap` is great, *but since it is a generator, which evaluates its sequence only when necessary, you have to ask it to give you some numbers explicitly*. With your code, you don't end up doing that. You could do this with your code instead:

```
less=[x for x in f(range(16))]<[x for x in g(range(16))],
equal=[x for x in f(range(16))]==[x for x in g(range(16))]
```

It would be just as fine to use `list()`. Of course, as abarnert has pointed out, it doesn't seem that you were asking for how to get them to compare equal to each other, so I may have said this last bit in vain.

Comment: Obviously if you turn all of them into lists, they're all going to return the same list. That's not what the OP's question is about. Also, `isgeneratorfunction` will always return false for any iterable (well, unless you create a pathological counter-example). I think you meant `isgenerator`. But that's not right either, because an `itertools.imap` instead is not a generator. Ultimately… what are you trying to do with that?

Comment: @abarnert I did mean `isgenerator()`, thank you. But I assumed it was a generator. So I'll edit that out.